# mod_pagespeed doesn't rewrite files when using with Nginx (reverse proxy) + Apache

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, mod-pagespeed

I use Nginx as a Web Server and Reverse Proxy for Apache on Ubuntu 14.04 Server.
The configuration looks exactly like this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-16-04-server

I use mod_pagespeed Apache module to optimize the pages. It works good for the page itself, removing whitespace and comments, so I can say it rewrites text/html.

However, it does not work on minifying JS, CSS or image files, combining CSS/JS or even rewriting images. No errors in Apache or Nginx log files.
In conf file I changed this to:

ModPagespeedRewriteLevel PassThrough

Update: I noticed many errors in Nginx error log file like this one:

/*

2017/03/18 23:55:38 [error] 3119#3119: *430 openat() "/etc/nginx/html/js/jquery/plugins/enquire.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /js/jquery/plugins/enquire.js HTTP/1.1", host: "blabla-bla.com", referrer: "http://blabla-bla.com/"

*/

Well, I see mod-pagespeed gets files from "/etc/nginx/html" not from root directory of website /var/www/user/data/www/blabla-bla.com/js/....
The referrer is: "http://blabla-bla.com/", even I am using "https://blabla-bla.com/" with https redirection.

Has anyone had this problem before?

I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Lookslike mod-pagespeed needs a special configuration in nginx?